# html link with parameters or form POST with parameters as hidden fields - Security and otherwise

Tags: html, forms, security, post, hyperlink

I have a simple contact database application written in php (PDO) and MySQL. It is a single file with a switch case statement. Default shows the table of contacts, case: add, edit, delete etc for the functions. All MySQL statements are prepared statements in PDO.

My question is:
Is it better to use a html link with parameters to move about or is it better to use a POST form with the parameters as hidden fields.

e.g. in the table listing the contacts, within each row is it better to have a link:

```
<a href="?mode=edit&contact_id=321">edit</a>
```

and get the 'mode' for the switch and the parameters from a $_GET statement

or is it better to have:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="edit"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="321" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="edit" />
</form>
```

I am interested from a security point of view as well as a functionality point of view. I have looked for similar questions here and found only one with a single answer that said a form is better. It had no explanation and 4 upvotes.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **definitely** better to go with the form. Why? Well, the URL navigation would be submitted via **[`GET`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_(HTTP))** requests, whereas the `<form>` submission is handled via **[`POST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))**. `GET` requests are **[exposed to the end-user](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post)**, whereas `POST` requests are not. As Stated by TeamTreeHouse in the previous link:

> Use POST when dealing with sensitive data.

Consider your former approach. A user sees `index.php?mode=edit&contact_id=321` appear in their browser. If they were malicious, they would easily be able to make the correlation to `index.php?mode=edit&contact_id=1`. They could easily type that in their browser. Assuming you don't have any other authentication mechanics set up, they'd be able to **[go ahead](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Parameter_Tampering)** and edit someone else's account.

The latter is *slightly* better. Although source code is not as obvious as an exposed URL, anyone is still able to view it, and find your hidden `321` contact. You might think that a malicious user cannot **edit** `hidden` form fields like they easily could with a query string, though this is not the case. They can download and create their own copy, simply replacing the `action` parameter with your own, thus submitting tampered data. There's even **[browser addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data)** for this, making it even easier!

To get around this, you're looking to combine the `<form>` method with an [**authentication token**](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/Europe/events/foaf-galway/papers/fp/token_based_authentication/). Generate a token that verifies the integrity of the form, ensuring that the form is not manipulated after being generated. It depends on exactly which language you're using on the back-end as to how to generate the token, but there's a great article for JSON web tokens **[here](https://auth0.com/learn/token-based-authentication-made-easy/)**.

Upon form submission, check the token matches what it was upon generation. If it matches, all is well, so you proceed. If it doesn't, the form has been manipulated, so you deny submission.

For further information, I recommend checking out **[OWASP's article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))** on Cross-Site Request Forgeries.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Very useful, thank you. I suppose I am thinking more in a broader security sense. I know that PDO and prepared statements is protecting my code from MySQL injection attacks, I just wanted to make sure that using forms (which I have chosen) is not leaving me open to attack from other exploits that I am not aware of. I am self taught and my knowledge is a little patchy. My application will be behind a membership wall on a https site.

Comment: HTTPS sadly does not protect you from CSRF, though an authentication token will protect your form. While prepared statements are a **great** preventative measure, you should additionally opt for the [**principle of least privilege**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) for your database itself. Also, WikiHow actually has a [**great article**](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) for a PHP / MySQLi combo covering a **tonne** of aspects, which could be easily adapted for PDO :)